# How to check for encoded OR unencoded character in query string with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want mod_rewrite rules for query string `?:hizzah=blah` to redirect to `brouahaha.html`

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} :hizzah=blah
RewriteRule .* brouahaha.html
```

Note the colon in front of hizzah.

The problem: this does not work if the colon is encoded. i.e. `example.com?:hizzah=blah` works but `example.com?%3Ahizzah=blah` does not.

I know having the colon is probably a bad idea because it's a reserved character, but its non-negotiable for now. It has to be this way.

What's the cleanest mod_rewrite way to allow the colon to be either plain or encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (:|\%3A)hizzah=blah [NC]
RewriteRule ^ brouahaha.html [L]
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way? Perhaps unescaping the query string before processing it? I couldn't find anything in mod_rewrite documentation to do this, but mod_rewrite is voodoo, so I maybe some voodoo practitioners know things beyond the documentation.

Comment: @MattYork You could use the RewriteMap (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) internal `unescape` function, but you need to have access to your VirtualHost/httpd.conf and it is more complex than above